# Github on Mac stuck on merging to master

Tags: github, github-for-mac

I could not find any similar question for this problem.

I am trying to merge my branch to the master using Mac GUI application from Github and it has been 30 minutes it is still spinning and no response 
There is no update on github.

Is this normal?

Comment: And what is the error message that you receive? After merging to local master, did you push your changes so that it can appear on github?

Comment: Is there any similarity with https://github.com/baldwindavid/github-for-mac-issues/issues/21 ? Any large file being merged?

Answer (score 0):

If your branch is merged, you need to push your changes to make them appear on github.